# Git asks a password for a wrong URL

Tags: git, github, repository

After creating a repository at GitHub, I follow the instruction given by GitHub:

```
$ echo "# test" >> README.md
$ git init
$ git add README.md
$ git commit -m "first commit"
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/user/test.git
$ git push -u origin master
```

(In the above URL the actual user name is replaced with `user`.)

Then I am asked (by Ksshaskpass) about

> Password for 'https://xxxxxxxx@github.com':

(The user name is not asked.) This `xxxxxxxx` is actually the initial password which I used when I created an account at GitHub. And my password is denied, so that I can not push the data.

I am expecting the output [like the following](http://backlogtool.com/git-guide/en/intro/intro4_2.html).

```
$ git push -u origin master
Username: <username>
Password: <password>
```

I removed `~/.gitconfig`, but the situation does not change. (The username is not asked yet.) There does not exist the directory `~/.git`. So I suspect that there is a wrong configuration file which I created a long time ago, but I can not find it.

**Could you give me any hint about this phenomenon?**

Env: openSUSE 13.2, git-2.1.4-13.1.x86_64

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the remote url to `ssh`.
https will keeep asking you for password every time you wish to run `git pull/push/fetch`.

Simply follow those steps and you will set up your ssh key in no time:

- Generate a new ssh key (or skip this step if you already have a key)
  `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your@email"`
- Once you have your key set in `home/.ssh` directory (or `Users/<your user>.ssh` under windows), open it and copy the content

---

#### How to add sh key to github account?

- Login to github account
- Click on the rancher on the top right (Settings)
  [image: github account settigns]
- Click on the `SSH keys`
  [image: ssh key section]
- Click on the `Add ssh key`
  [image: Add ssh key]
- Paste your key and save
- Change the remote url `git remote set-url origin <new_ssh_url>`

And you all set to go :-)

Comment: I was trying only HTTPS because it is recommended. But I have switched to SSH, after reading your answer. It works (without the hyphen before `rsa`). Thank you very much.

Comment: Sure. :-) the -t is the certificate type. the default is rsa

Answer (score 1):

Removing the wrong information for ksshaskpass from kwallet may help.

Answer (score 1):

Under Linux, my fix was to open the KWallpaperManager, search (using the search bar) for the wrongly set password as the user account that becomes part of the wrong URL, delete that entry and tried again to push the commit(s). The credentials process started from scratch, so when it asked for the account (misleading the user by writing "Password" aside the text box), entered the git user name, then the password in the second dialog. All was set correctly and I could continue git operations in any client (command line or GUI).